# Display special characters when using print statement

Tags: python, printing, escaping, character

I would like to display the escape characters when using print statement. E.g.

```
a = "Hello\tWorld\nHello World"
print a
Hello   World
Hello World
```

I would like it to display:
    "Hello\tWorld\nHello\sWorld"

Answer (score 216):

Use [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

```
a = "Hello\tWorld\nHello World"
print(repr(a))
# 'Hello\tWorld\nHello World'
```

Note you do not get `\s` for a space. I hope that was a typo...?

But if you really do want `\s` for spaces, you could do this:

```
print(repr(a).replace(' ',r'\s'))
```

Comment: Python 3 is: `print(repr(a))`

Answer (score 20):

Do you merely want to print the string that way, or do you want that to be the internal representation of the string?  If the latter, create it as a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) by prefixing it with `r`: `r"Hello\tWorld\nHello World"`.

```
>>> a = r"Hello\tWorld\nHello World"
>>> a # in the interpreter, this calls repr()
'Hello\\tWorld\\nHello World'
>>> print a
Hello\tWorld\nHello World
```

Also, `\s` is not an escape character, except in regular expressions, and then it still has a much different meaning than what you're using it for.