# Python - print string to screen, include \n in output

Tags: python, printing

I have the following code:

```
pattern = "something.*\n" #intended to be a regular expression

fileString = some/path/to/file

numMatches = len( re.findall(pattern, fileString, 0) )

print "Found ", numMatches, " matches to ", pattern, " in file."
```

I want the user to be able to see the '\n' included in pattern. At the moment, the '\n' in pattern writes a newline to the screen. So the output is like:

```
Found 10 matches to something.*
 in file.
```

and I want it to be:

```
Found 10 matches to something.*\n in file.
```

Yes, pattern.replace("\n", "\n") does work. But I want it to print all forms of escape characters, including \t, \e etc. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has already been asked, hopefully this points you in the correct direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/python-display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement

Comment: `displayPattern = "something.*\s"` use `\s` to find the newline character

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `repr(pattern)` to print the `\n` the way you need.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
displayPattern = "something.*\\n"
print "Found ", numMatches, " matches to ", displayPattern, " in file."
```

You'll have to specify a different string for each case of the pattern - one for matching and one for displaying. In the display pattern, notice how the `\` character is being escaped: `\\`.

Alternatively, use the built-in [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) function:

```
displayPattern = repr(pattern)
print "Found ", numMatches, " matches to ", displayPattern, " in file."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print repr(string)
#or
print string.__repr__()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why use `string.__repr__()` instead of `repr(string)`?

Comment: @ntpeterson I didn't realize it existed until just now. Changing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Also another way to use repr is with the %r format string. I would normally write this as

```
print "Found %d matches to %r in file." % (numMatches, pattern)
```