# Using replace method in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, escaping

How do I ignore all escape characters in a string?

**Fx:** `\n \t %s`

So if I have a string:

```
text = "Hello \n My Name is \t John"
```

Now if I print the string the output will be different than the actual string:

```
Hello
 My Name is      John
```

How can I print the 'actual string' like this:

```
Hello \n My Name is \t John
```

Here is an example, which doesn't work:

```
text = "Hello \n My Name is \t John"
text.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\t', '\\t')
print text
```

***This does not work!*** No difference

I have looked at some topics where you could remove them, but I DO not want that. How do I ignore them? So we can see the actual string?

Comment: `str.replace` doesn't work in-place. You have to assign the return value back to your variable.

Comment: You asking how to ignore all escape characters, and checked an answer is not about that. Logic!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Display special characters when using print statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/python-display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method didn't work because strings are immutable. You need to reassign `text.replace(...)` to text in order to make it work.

```
>>> text = text.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\t', '\\t')
>>> print text
Hello \n My Name is \t John
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) on the string before printing it:

```
>>> text = "Hello \n My Name is \t John"
>>> print repr(text)
'Hello \n My Name is \t John'
>>> print repr(text)[1:-1]  # [1:-1] will get rid of the ' on each end
Hello \n My Name is \t John
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little but very usefull method, use **r** :

```
a=r"Hey\nGuys\tsup?"
print (a)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Hey\nGuys\tsup?
>>>
```

So, for your problem:

```
text =r"Hello\nMy Name is\t John"
text = text.replace(r'\n', r'\\n').replace(r'\t', r'\\t')
print (text)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Hello\\nMy Name is\\t John
>>>
```

You have to define text variable AGAIN, because strings are unmutable.