# How to print "\" in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, backslash

```
print "\\"
```

It print me [image] in console...

But I want to get string `\`

How to get string string `\`?

Comment: The statement you gave correctly prints the `\\` for me. Is this the only thing printing wrongly, does it get printed wrongly, even if surrounded by other characters?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/python-display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement

Comment: what operating system?

Answer (score 3):

There's clearly some sort of configuration with your console that's wrong. Doing this:

```
print "\\"
```

Clearly prints `\` for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add letter r to string before quotes (r for raw). It will ignore all special symbols.

For example

```
>>> print '\x63\\ Hello \n\n8'
c\ Hello

8
>>> print r'\x63\\ Hello \n\n8'
\x63\\ Hello \n\n8
```

So printing backslash is `print r'\'`

Comment: This rapidly becomes the better answer when you have more than one special character in your string!