# Adding letters to each element of a list

Tags: python, list

I try to add "G:" in the beginning and a backslash before every point of each element in a list. Therefore I created this example list1:

```
list1 = ['AEX.EN', 'AXAL.OQ', 'AAPIOE.NW']
```

And I need something like list2:

```
list2 = ['G:AEX\.EN', 'G:AXAL\.OQ', 'G:AAPIOE\.NW']
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: How would you do it if you only had one element that you needed to modify?

Comment: Did you try to solve this? Please share your code.

Comment: For only one element I tried it with .insert(0,"G:") but the position of the backslash is not always the same.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow expects you to search for existing solutions before posting a question. This is a common question with many answers out there.

Comment: @jarmod sorry, I am quite new here & I will do that next time

Comment: can anyone explain why escape characters are working in string in list but outside list strings behave normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
>>> ['G:' + i.replace('.', '\\.') for i in list1]
['G:AEX\\.EN', 'G:AXAL\\.OQ', 'G:AAPIOE\\.NW']
>>>
```

In this case I prefer `re.escape`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ['G:' + re.escape(i) for i in list1]
['G:AEX\\.EN', 'G:AXAL\\.OQ', 'G:AAPIOE\\.NW']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` for join string then use `replace()` like below:

```
>>> list1 = ['AEX.EN', 'AXAL.OQ', 'AAPIOE.NW']

>>> [('G:'+l).replace('.','\.') for l in list1]
['G:AEX\\.EN', 'G:AXAL\\.OQ', 'G:AAPIOE\\.NW']
```

Comment: > list2 = ['G:AEX\.EN', 'G:AXAL\.OQ', 'G:AAPIOE\.NW']

>print(list2)

> OUTPUT: ['G:AEX\\.EN', 'G:AXAL\\.OQ', 'G:AAPIOE\\.NW']


for i in list2:
 print(i)

> OUTPUT:
 G:AEX\.EN
G:AXAL\.OQ
G:AAPIOE\.NW

Why this is happening?

Comment: @ujjwal_bansal this happen in python, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491682/how-to-print-in-python)