# How does pydtmx or libdtmx return the FNC1 character

Tags: python, datamatrix

Does anyone know what  character FNC1 returns as in pydmtx? I'm using pydmtx to read a variety of Datamatrix tags which include variable length elements that I need to parse.  Pydmtx is a wrapper for libdmtx, [The changelog for libdmtx 0.7.0](http://libdmtx.sourceforge.net/display.php?text=ChangeLog-0.7.2.txt) says it added reader supports for FNC1. I'd really like to do something like this:

```
def split_tag(tag_string):    
    FNC1="\u{what_I'm_looking_for}" 
    return string.split(tag_string, FNC1)
```

Yes, I understand tag elements will include prefixes and fixed length tags will not have a FNC1 between them and will have to be handled separately in my parser.

Alternately if there's a good python opensource library that reads and parses DataMatrix you'll save me about half a day on this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/python-display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement) solved it for me.  Pydmtx returns FNC1 as "\x1d" aka [information separator 3](http://www.charbase.com/001d-unicode-information-separator-three)

Answer (score 3):

The GS1 Application Standards for every GS1-specialised barcode symbology (including GS1 DataMatrix) specify that FNC1 characters that are used in a field separator role must be decoded as ASCII 29 (GS). Be aware that there are other roles for FNC1 characters in such symbols that are treated differently which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322815/2568535) explains.

The ["extraction" part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760872/2568535) explains how to properly parse GS1-formatted data.