# Python: How to retain string as is (with '\n') while printing?

Tags: python, solr

I am printing a string from a json url. It prints it in different lines. I want to print the string as is (with the '\n' intact).

**My code:-**

```
TestDocs= urllib.request.urlopen("solr url").read()
TestDocs_obj = json.loads(TestDocs.decode())

Docs = []
for i in TestDocs_obj['response']['docs']:
    matchObj = re.findall(r'open(s)?|education|(?i)sue', i['sentence'])
    if not matchObj:
        Doc = i["sentence"]
        print(Doc)
        Docs.append(Doc)
```

**it is printing:-**

Microsoft buys a company.

It is located in Spain.

**I want:-**

Microsoft buys a company.\nIt is located in Spain

Comment: Question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/python-display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repr`to escape special characters.

```
s = 'hello\nworld'
print(repr(s)[1:-1])
```