# Python - How to print variable that has been assigned to an indentation?

Tags: python

Once I assign an indentation to a variable, how can I print that specific thing that I assigned ? For example, this prints whitespace

```
delim = "\t"
print(delim)
```

whereas I would like to print out `\t`. I do not want to assign delim to be `"\\t"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display special characters when using print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477823/display-special-characters-when-using-print-statement)

Comment: By the way, that character is not called "indentation," though indentation is a result of pressing that key when typing code in a text editor. The character is called "tab" which is an abbreviation of "tabulation."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`print(repr(delim))` will have the desired output

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
delim = r"\t"
print(delim)
```