# how to ignore \n and show it as plaintext in python

Tags: python

I want to print this text 'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'

like this

```
'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'
```

but when I tried to do that its printing like this '

```
aÀXysc 
§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ
```

how can I ignore\n

Comment: Scape it! `\\n`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6477823/

Comment: `print('aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'.replace('\n', '\\n'))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `r` to make `\n` lose its special meaning.

```
print(r'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ')
# aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply scape `\` by using `\\`

```py
>> print('aÀXysc \\n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ')
aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ
```

or you can use a raw string by prepending an `r` to the string

```py
>> print(r'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ')
aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `repr` function to get the string representation of the value:

```
>>> print(repr('aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'))
'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print it as a raw string by prefixing it with `r`.

```
>>> print(r'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ')
aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

First Method:
You can try use the `repr function` like so:

```
my_string = 'aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'
print(repr(my_string))
```

Second Method: Use the double \ back lash, like so:

```
my_string = 'aÀXysc \\n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ'
print(my_string)
```

Output:

```
aÀXysc \n§Ä tIÄ¡p¶ntÃ
```